# If $a$ , $b$, $c$ are positive integers satisfying the following $(a^2 +2)(b^2+3)(c^2+4)=2014$ What is the value of $ a+b+c $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ , $b$, $c$ are positive integers satisfying the following
$(a^2 +2)(b^2+3)(c^2+4)=2014$

What is the value  of $ a+b+c $

I need  details  because  i don't  know  how to solve simlar  problems ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint:  the prime factorization of $2014$ is quite simple.

Comment: @lulu  ok  $2014=2*19*53$  then $a^2+2=2$  and so $a=0$  ; $b^2+3=19$ and so $b = 4$  , also $c^2 +4= 53$ and so $c= 7  $so the sum a+b+c=11 , but a is not positive integer

Comment: pray    it is impossible to do this with $a \neq 0$

Comment: You've done the best you could.  I expect they meant to specify "non-negative" integers.

Comment: there is another option $a^2+2$  should be  $a^2-2$

Comment: Oh, if $a =0$ is not acceptable then this is simply not possible as all factors are greater than 2 and it is impossible to factor 2014 into three factors each greater than 2.  I think the question meant "non-negative"  You want to avoid $-4 + 7 = 3$.  Although finding out all solutions would also be a fair question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2014 = 2*19*53$

So each of the $a^2 + 2, b^2+3, c^2 + 4$ are some combination of $2, 19, 53$.

As none of them can equal 1, the must be that one of them equals $2$, another $19$ and the third $53$.  What possible numbers work?  (Note: just by looking only one can be small enough to equal $2$.)

Answer (score 5):

Try factoring $2014$. Then you might see how to find $a$, $b$, and $c$.
If you need more help just ask!

Answer (score 1):

let us consider following program

```
    z=input('enter your number : ');
  string='';
    for ii=2:z
       s=0;
       while z/ii==floor(z/ii) % check if  z is divisible by ii
           z=z/ii;
           s=s+1;
       end
       if s>0
                str =[num2str(ii) '^' num2str(s) ];

                   string=strcat(string,str);
                   string= strcat(string,'*'); 
             % If z = 1, no more divisions are necessary, 
            % thus breaks the loop and quits
            if z == 1
                break
            end
        end

    end
    string=string(1:end-1);% remove last sign of multiplicaiton
fprintf('prime factorization is %s\n',string);
```

we would have

```
>> integer_factorization
enter your number : 2014
prime factorization is 2^1*19^1*53^1
```

now

```
 x=2
y=19
z=53
```

$a^2+2=2$

$a^2=0$

which means $a=0$

$c^2+4=53$

$c^2=53-4=49$

which  means  that $c=7$  or $c=-7$ depend  we have positive  integers or integers and  also

$b^2+3=19$

we have $ b=4 $ or $b-4$

Comment: Thank you sir , Excellent  work , the problem is about  positive integers

Comment: it seems that $a=0$

Comment: but 0 is not positive number

Comment: $a^2+2 $  should be $a^2-2$ maybe it is typo in book